# Arranging images in Stacklayout added through a loop

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i am using a for loop to add 198 items, half numbers and half images for an app just to get familiar with xamarin forms but am unable to switch from vertical to horizontal. the desired output is to have 4 images with their serial number in one line.

EDIT: i am unable to get it to display in multiple lines

```
Image[] show = new Image[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    show[i]=new Image{ Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
    show[i].WidthRequest = 30;
    show[i].HeightRequest = 30;
    show[i].Source = images[i];
}

for (int i=0;i<99;i++)
{
    if (i % 4 == 0)
    {
        layout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        layout.Spacing = 15;
        layout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        layout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = (i+1).ToString() });
        layout.Spacing = 10;
        layout.Children.Add(show[i]); 
    }
    else
    {
        layout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
        layout.Spacing = 10;
        layout.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        layout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = (i+1).ToString() });
        layout.Children.Add(show[i]);
    }
}
```

This is the current output[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4oO4.png)

Comment: Sounds great. Let us know if you run into any issues.

Comment: it is not displaying what i want it to, thats the problem, please check the image

Comment: Hmm so are you wanting the numbers to the left of each image. Not sure what you want it to look like. What do you mean you are unable to switch from vertical to horizontal. Edit: Are you wanting each image on it's own line?

Comment: I want it to be like this:  
<br\>
1 @   2 $   3 %   2 $   4 ^   5 !  
<br\>
6 $   7 ^   8 )   9 -   10 ?   11 $

Comment: I'm sorry, I might just be bad at envisioning things. Could you create a quick and simple image of what you want? Does not have to be pretty or anything.

Comment: Some thing like this ![Valid XHTML][Image]
[Image]:http://cache1.asset-cache.net/xc/105867166.jpg?v=2&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=pap42lj8wK6OAbXAk5nbFhDTA_0vfSVyvK40asTb610oBtJ40IAWKeS9U1cBsgU-0

Comment: Awesome, so where would the numbers to be placed in relation to that image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a grid, but to use layouts you would need something more like this:

```
        var outerLayout = new StackLayout {Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical};
        var innerLayout = new StackLayout();
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            if (i%4 == 0)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                    outerLayout.Children.Add(innerLayout);
                innerLayout = new StackLayout {Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal};
            }
            innerLayout.Children.Add(new Label { Text = (i + 1).ToString() });
            innerLayout..Children.Add(show[i]); 
        }
        outerLayout.Children.Add(innerLayout);
        MainPage = new ContentPage {Content = outerLayout};
```

This creates an outer vertical layout to hold all the horizontal layouts, then creates a horizontal layout for each group that you want displayed horizontally.